# How to determine the bandwidth required for on-prem to Azure ASR?

Tags: azure, azure-site-recovery

I'm trying to estimate the cost for ASR in Azure pricing calculator.
The scenario: to set up DR from on-prem (10vms = 5tb) to Azure with VPN connection established between on-prem and Azure. Idk why they need VPN but yeah.

Question is, how many bandwidth is required in this scenario? Do I need to quote 2 bandwidth (1 for failback, 1 for VPN)  How to determine the size of bandwidth required for each? does it has to follow the size of on-prem VMs(5tb) since we are replicating the whole storage right?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run deployment planner. Reference link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-deployment-planner

The tool provides the following details:

[image]